# Why ffmpeg takes so long time to decode 1 frame from high resolution gif

Tags: python, ffmpeg, freeze

I am working on gif to png decode. My command is like:

> ffmpeg -probesize 20M -y -i "GIF_High resolution_4952x7000.gif" -y
>   -frames:v 1 %03d.png

Input: gif (4952x7000)

Output: png

And here's output result:
[image]

It takes about 13 seconds. 
If I use `python` to call `subprocess.Popen()` to execute it, it causes UI to hang.
And I found something weird in `Process Monitor`:
[image]

It stuck in process profiling for a long time. I don't know why. Can anyone help? I'll appreciate that.

Comment: Your picture size is 35 megapixels ! Also, the GIF decoder isn't using any vectorized processing.

Comment: What happens if you remove `-probesize 20M -y`? Also... Are you able to play/decode the GIF with Python tools only and also step frame-by-frame? If yes, why not step through each frame and save shown pixels as image (PNG) without FFmpeg?